# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position ... when reading text file by pandas read_csv

Tags: python, text

I want to read a text file by using pandas `read_csv`, but get an error 
`'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 28: invalid start byte`

I have tried `read_csv` with `encoding='latin1'`, `encoding='iso-8859-1'` or `encoding='cp1252'` from other posts. But all of them not work for me. For `encoding='latin1'`, I get an error of `Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 6, saw 3`

This is how I read file:

```py
df=pd.read_csv("004.txt", encoding="utf-8")
print(df.head())
```

Could someone help me with this issue? thanks

Comment: Looks like it's not a valid CSV file.

Comment: Could you please show us the first 7 lines in your csv ?

Comment: I also tried another way to open text file, but get an error as well.
 `f = open("004.txt", "r")
print(f.read()) ` 

The error `'cp950' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 28: illegal multibyte sequence`

Comment: This is how my file looks like by opening text file directly with notepad

`Pediatric Pulmonology 38:161?67 (2004) 

Nasal Corticosteroids for Children With Snoring 


1,2 1,2

Emmanouel I. Alexopoulos, MD, Athanasios G. Kaditis, MD, * Efthimia Kalampouka, MD,1 

2 21

Eleni Kostadima, MD, Nikiforos V. Angelopoulos, MD, Vasiliki Mikraki, MD, 
Nikolaos Skenteris, MD,1 and Konstantinos Gourgoulianis, MD3`

Comment: can you share the file using github?

Comment: I am new to this platform and I don't know how to show my file here...so I upload my file here

[link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1viMv6WXZ5yodvkybCaOwunpLE6C4t66b)

Comment: I have uploaded my "004.txt" to github as well. [link](https://github.com/shanrulin/code)

Comment: this is an entire journal paper in mostly 1-2 word rows...what are you trying to achieve reading this with pandas?

Comment: I want to do text mining for all text file I have...each text file content as one row
but I encounter problem when I try to read one file to python to see my data.

Comment: The error message that you get for `latin1` encoding isn't a failure to decode but rather a failure to read it as a csv file since it manifestly is no such thing. This suggests that `latin1` is the relevant encoding.

Comment: how did you generate this txt file from the source? something went screwy

Comment: No, I did not generate the txt file...professor gave us for assignment to analyze

Answer (score 0):

Reason for

```
tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 6, saw 3
```

The file is not proper CSV format. You have 1 - 5 lines with no ' , ' and at the 6th line you have 2 ' , '.

However you can read the file using file read operations.
Follow these steps:
1. Open the file in notepad.
2. Click Save as option
3. On the left of save button you can select encoding.
4. Select utf - 8 as encoding.
5. Try this code

These steps will take care of

```
utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 28: invalid start byte
```

code :

```
f = open('004.txt','r')
data = f.read()
print(data)
```

Comment: I have tried to open with Notepad and save as 'utf - 8', then tried your code, but get an error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp950' codec can't decode byte 0xee in position 5807: illegal multibyte sequence`

Comment: Save the file as '.txt'

Comment: sorry that I did not describe it correctly. I follow your instruction and save it as '.txt' with 'utf-8' but get the error

Comment: Try by specifying encoding as utf-8

Comment: yes, the error I mentioned above `'cp950' codec can't decode byte 0xee in position 5807: illegal multibyte sequence` was returned when I save my file as '.txt' file with "utf8' encoding.